# How to use protoBuf for struct serialization

Tags: c#, struct, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I want to serialize a class with protoBuf. My class has a field that is a `struct`. How can I serialize it?

```
[ProtoContract]
class P
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    private T t;

    public P()
    { }
}

[ProtoContract]
public struct T
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int a;

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int b;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What happened? Also: why is that a `struct` (it isn't obvious that this is a classic choice for a `struct`)?

Answer (score 1):

Just serialize/deserialize it - it should work fine. Because `t` is `private`, I added an accessor (that is only used by my code below - this accessor is completely unrelated to serialization):

```
public T T { get { return t; } set { t = value; } }
```

And then this works just fine:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        P p = new P { T = new T { a = 123, b = 456 } },
            clone;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(ms, p);
            ms.Position = 0;
            clone = Serializer.Deserialize<P>(ms);
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine(clone.T.a); // 123
        System.Console.WriteLine(clone.T.b); // 456
    }
}
```